# Query one field equal to another array field?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose the collection like this:

```
{
   movie : 1,
   List : [ 1 , 2 ,5 , 6 ]
},
{
   movie : 2,
   List : [ 3, 5, 7 ]
},
{
   movie : 3,
   List : [ 1, 3, 6 ]
}
```

I want get all documents that 'movie' exist in the 'List'.

How do I write the query or aggregate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal form of this is with native operators using `.aggregate()` with [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$setIsSubset": [
          { "$map": { "input": ["A"], "as": "el", "in": "$movie" } },
          "$List"
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

Or if you don't have [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) available in your MongoDB version, use the `$where` query condition instead:

```js
db.collection.find(function() {
  return this.List.indexOf(this.movie) != 1
})
```

Both have the basic approach of looking for the value of one field being present within the array field in the document.

There are a couple of different forms you can use with `$redact`, such as this [`$anyElementTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) call:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$anyElementTrue": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$List",
            "as": "el",
            "in": { "$eq": [ "$$el", "$movie" ] }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

As well as a shorter syntax of the original with MongoDB 3.2:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$setIsSubset": [
          ["$movie"],
          "$List"
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

Where just as with the usage of [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) originally the `["$movie"]` make the single element an array/set for which you compare using [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/). In the latter case the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) is just applying a condition to each element of the array to return an array of `true/false` values which is then reduced to a logical single `true/false` by [`$anyElementTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/).